# Passing PHP value to Javascript file in (Wordpress Plugin Dev)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

on my main plugin.php file, I get/fetch the file from wp_postmeta database based on custom post type id

> $wpsv_save_metadata = get_post_meta($post->ID);

Then based on this ID, I can get the value such as wpsv_video_width, wpsv_video_height, etc using :

> $wpsv_save_metadata['wpsv_video_width'][0];

but I can not pass that value (wpsv_video_width, wpsv_video_height) to my javascript file.

How to pass the value to my javascript file so I can change the width (win.style.width) and height (win.style.height) dynamically :

```js
function yScrollHandler(){
  var win = document.getElementById("styleku-video-container");
  if((window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) >= 1000){
  //win.style.webkitTransition = "right 0.7s ease-in-out 0s";
  win.style.transition = "right 0.7s ease-in-out 0s";
  win.style.right = "0px";
  win.style.position = "fixed";
  win.style.bottom = "0px";
  win.style.padding = "10px";
  win.style.width = "400px";
  win.style.height = "295px";
  } else {
  win.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}
window.onscroll = yScrollHandler;
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

[has a neat example](https://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) similar to your question.

Comment: Thanks, It works. I can get the value from to my js file. However I can not get the value inside the `function yScrollHandler(){ win.style.width = 400; win.style.height = 225;}` I want to replace the 400 and 225 with variable. Please help.

Comment: I just realized, it's a little tricky because I use `window.onscroll = yScrollHandler;` to run the function. it can get the value if I use `window.onload = yScrollHandler;`. Any idea how to get the value, when running the function using  `window.onscroll` ?

Answer (score 0):

just create javascript variable first and after attach your js file to use that js global variable inside your js file. like below.

```
<?php
  $width = $wpsv_save_metadata['wpsv_video_width'][0];
  $height = $wpsv_save_metadata['wpsv_video_height'][0];
?>
<script>
  var width = <?php echo $width; ?> // use width variable in your js file
  var height = <?php echo $height; ?> // use height variable in your js file
</script>
<script src="your js file path"></script>
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but still no luck. NOTE : the javascript is not on the header. it's on a stand along javascript file

Comment: ok but you need to add javascript after global variable assign, also do not use document.ready in assign global variable.

Comment: if then it not work just add document.ready inside your js file once and try

Comment: if not work then try <script async src="your js file"></script> or <script defer src="your js file"></script> once

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method if loading your js from a separate site.

If you are not loading your js into your theme, then you can't use wp_localize_script, so you need an alternate way to include the **`wp-load.php`** file from the root folder of WordPress.  Create two files in your plugin folder:

**js-template.js**

/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/js/js-template.js

```
var mymessage = '[[my-message]]'; // in php use str_replace() to replace this
console.log('mymessage', mymessage);
```

**get-js.php**

/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/js/get-js.php

```
<?php

// Drop this into your plugin folder and access it directly
// https://example.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/js/get-js.php

// It will load a js file named js-template.js

/**
 * Finds the wp root folder.
 * Navigate through the parent directories to find the wp-load.php file.
 * Stop after reaching 10 directories up, so we don't run into a 
 * recursion error.
 * 
 * @param $path directory to look into
 * @param $max_recursive the max number of parent directories to navigate into
 * 
 * @return string|boolean Either a string of the path or false if the max recursion is reached
 */
function find_parent_wp_root($path = './', $max_recursive = 10) {

    if( $max_recursive === 0 )
        return false;

    if( file_exists( realpath($path) . '/wp-load.php' ) ) {
        return realpath($path) . '/';
    } else {
        return find_parent_wp_root($path . '../', $max_recursive-1);
    }
}

$www_root = find_parent_wp_root($path = './');

if( ! $www_root ) {
    http_response_code(404);
} else {

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require( $www_root . 'wp-blog-header.php');

    $js = file_get_contents('js-template.js');

    $js = str_replace('[[my-message]]', 'some new value', $js);

    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo $js;
}
```